# Como atualizar a referência de um nó no Firebase em outro nó?

Tags: firebase

[image: Estrutura do banco]

Tenho na estrutura do banco de dados com 2 nós ("local" e "lote"). Dentro da estrutura de "lote", tenho a referência de um "local" no atributo "local_lote", como descrito na imagem. Ao atualizar o atributo (capacidade local) do nó "local", a referência dele dentro de "lote" não foi atualizada. Esse procedimento de atualização deve ser manual? Tem alguma forma de atualizar automático? Sou novo com Firebase, logo essa maneira seria a melhor maneira de estruturar? Grato desde já!

Answer (score 0):

seja bem-vindo a nossa comunidade.

Respondendo as suas dúvidas:

A primeira coisa que observei pelo print da sua tela é que você está utilizando o Realtime Database. Há real necessidade de usar o Realtime database? Seu sistema tem muita concorrência e precisa de alta disponibilidade? Acredito que não. Portanto, ao invés do Realtime Database, utilize o Firestore.

Utilizando o Firestore, você tem um recurso interessante que são as subcollections (subcoleções), justamente para você fazer associações semelhantes.

Entendi que na modelagem que você fez, um local pode conter diversos lotes associados a ele correto?

No Firestore, basta criar a coleção "local" e em cada documento, você pode criar uma subcoleção "lotes" e aí sim nele você adiciona elementos lotes. Assim você evita duplicidade de referência e a organização fica muito melhor.

Você encontrará bastante coisa nessa [documentação oficial do Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)